# Disable an image button in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Here is the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField Text="Name" DataField="Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" CommandName="DeleteItem" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <ajax:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="DeleteCbe" runat="server" TargetControlID="DeleteButton"  ConfirmText="Continue with delete?" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

i want to disable DeleteButton when "Ok" is clicked. this will prevent the user from clicking the image several times while it is still deleting the data in the db. is this possible? how do i do it? thanks.

Comment: thanks ScarletGarden for editing my question -- looks better now.

Comment: Even if you disable buttons client-side, the user can still trigger a post back by refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a script on my blog that will disable *all* the buttons on the form once a postback begins. This way, they will not be able to trigger *any* other postback until that one completes.

[How to Disable the Submit Button of a Web Form](http://blog.josh420.com/archives/2008/02/how-to-disable-the-submit-button-ofweb-form.aspx)

This solution is very easy to integrate into your app.

Comment: thanks josh. i'll go to your blog and i'll try to use script in my codes.